# Not able to delete a program

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, spyware, avast, anti-spyware

I am using a netbook of samsung with windows 7 starter service pack 1 32 bit.
I am exhausted with a program known as 'Plugin.exe' i don't know how it came but whenever i start my program it opens up and i have noticed that it only opens in when my internet connection is on.

I Tried-:

- I ran full scan of avast antivirus and also grimefighter too but no luck.
- I checked the file in startup programs and add or remove remove programs but i didn't find any such file.
- I tried to change the format of the file so that it stops running and gets damaged by changing its format into pdf,txt but nothing happened.
- I tried to delete the file by Eraser and file shredder(avast) but i was unable to remove the program.

What I am Doing Now:

I have blocked that program by setting avast into hardened mode, but now whenever i open my internet connection avast notification pops-up and troubles me by stating a notification that 'avast has found a harmful program C:/Plugin.exe as i close the avast notification it opens up in another second and this process goes on.

Comment: If you have a DVD drive, try using a Linux Live DVD and boot your system. Access your hard drive C;\ , locate the plugin.exe and delete it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Is there any easy for removing it@Prasanna <br>

Comment: Sorry i am not able to search it or find it as i think it has hidden in my system i tried spyware removal tool (spy bot) but nothing came out as an expected result

Comment: @hackwarewright what was the issue? Was it a malware or a legitimate program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the check in Avast for Plugins.exe.
2. Start your browser, let it connect to the internet. As you said Plugins.exe shoudl start up.
3. Download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Run it with elevated rights (Run as administrator).
4. Search for plugins.exe.
5. Understand where is it located. Verify if that is a valid program or no. Using process explorer, see if you can get the Autostart location.
6. If no, see who is its parent. There could another process spawning it. If yes, suspend that program. Suspend plugins.exe
7. Kill both.
8. Remove the file.

Hopefully this should help you.